# How do I close my chat room?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, chat

Today, I created [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4818/room-1568975) chat room on SO. I have no option to be able to close it. Can it be possible to have an option to close chat room ? or maybe if can't do that right now, Can i make a request to a moderator to close it?

Comment: While you wait for a mod to close it, you can make it a gallery and make sure you are the only room owner and no users have explicit write access, so no one except you (or mods) will be allowed to chat.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For now, post a message in the room asking a moderator to delete it, and then click the arrow to the left of the message and flag it for mod attention:

[image: Screenshot of the post menu]

Answer (score 10):

Your chat room will be frozen, if there are no messages for 14 days; after that, it will eventually expire if there is no activity. There is a minimum number of messages after which a room will never be deleted, but it will still freeze after 14 days.