# Error while trying to parse "Flag for moderator" text

Tags: bug, status-completed, chat

I was trying to close [this room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10191/sql-queries) in StackOverflow following [this advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111545/how-do-i-close-my-chat-room).

So I posted the text there and flagged that very same comment for moderator attention. A popup appeared asking me why I considered it should be flagged and I, applying all of my creativity, copied the same content of the message:

```
Based on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111545/how-do-i-close-my-chat-room), in order to get this room closed I need to flag this very same message. Please, close this room. Thanks!
```

The funny thing is that the flag itself returned the following error (see on top):

[image: Screenshot]

I guess there must be some error while trying to parse the link or maybe the message was too long. In either case, I don't know if the comment ended up flagged or not and also the error could be a bit friendlier than `parseerror`... Maybe `Parse error` will do :)

Comment: Refreshing the page will usually resolve situations where you're receiving this error (although I've never had it happen when flagging)

Comment: @Tim You're probably referring to this: http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/1009091#1009091

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The "flag for moderator" text is restricted to 200 characters, but the client-side validation erroneously allowed 400. So if you typed between 201 and 400 characters, the client would happily send it, but the server would choke on it.

Fresh JavaScript with a fix for this is out, get your daily dose today!

Comment: `Ctrl+F5! Ctrl+F5!`

Comment: The cat ate my characters!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: No I didn't.