# Sockpuppet troll: Can't flag for moderator attention: parseerror

Tags: support, status-completed, chat

Related to this question: [Error while trying to parse "Flag for moderator" text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131912/error-while-trying-to-parse-flag-for-moderator-text)

I'm trying to flag [this (and related)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4382503#4382503) for moderator attention. Here is my flag verbatim:

> user1131997 is back, disrupting the room with unconstructive, highly off-topic questions and ditto banter. We try to ignore the user. @user1317084 might be a sockpuppet (judging from the quality and subject of the SO questions). Thanks for the attention

Sadly, I can't submit the flag. A popover message reports `parseerror`.

**Update** The same user has - in addition to earlier hints - now confirmed his sockpuppetry:

https://chat.stackoverflow.com/messages/4382774/history

> and so what? you could try block me as much as you want, but you won't stop me from joining this room [*as user user1489093*]

**Update 2** More sockpuppet accounts have *since* been created by the same user:

> [see you later :)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4383044#4383044)  [*as user user1501635*]

**Update 3** Personal threats have now been received from this user:

> [maybe there would good poistion to take you IP and look at you real life :)](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/4383338#4383338) [*as user user1501635*]

Comment: @sal [user1131997](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1131997) doesn't seem to be a user on [so] as far as I can tell...

Comment: @sal - ahh... Well  as you can see from their profile link - `/users/1447842/user1131997`, the **actual** id of the user is `1447842`. The `user1131997` seems like the screen name that they chose... weird...

Comment: FYI, the error happens because the mod message is too long; something appears broken with the client-side length validation.

Comment: @balpha thanks for clearing that up. I had a suspicion, but my repeated trims didn't reach the limit then :)

Comment: @Lix well, not everyone has a prime number username. It's l33t!

Comment: *Fun fact: 99.99% of the people who threaten to come to your house based on your IP do not even know what "IP" means (much less understand how it works).*

Comment: @Urist: While this might well be true, that doesn't mean threatening other users, however laughable executed, is behavior that should be shrugged off.

Comment: @sbi: True, bad choice of words on my part.

Comment: My IP is 348.25.242.994. come at me bro!

Comment: And while you're at it, please also hack 127.0.0.1. Thank you.

Answer (score 18):

Well, while my American friends celebrate their separation today, I have done quite the opposite: I just came back from a merge fest :)

Thanks for the pointers.

As for the parseerror, see my comment on your question as well as [Error while trying to parse "Flag for moderator" text](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131912/error-while-trying-to-parse-flag-for-moderator-text), which I admittedly missed previously. In my defense, I was on vacation in Jamaica when that was posted. Soon come!

Comment: [Hope you have] Enjoy[ed] your vacation!

Answer (score 5):

If you are unable to flag the message from within the chat room,  you can always raise a flag on [one of the posts made](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1501635/user1501635) by [one of the puppets](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1317084/user1317084) and explain the situation in a custom flag.  The mods will be able to track down the users activity from there.

Don't forget to include links to the messages and any other information you feel would be relevant as well to make it easier for the mods :)