# Why is option not available to close a chat room I created?

Tags: discussion, chat

[This question already present](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111545/how-do-i-close-my-chat-room) but I want to know the reason why I'm not able to close a chat room which still don't have any participant or any message.I have been receiving close votes on my question so I created a chat room to discus it with others the reason but with an edit I've been able to remove the doubts as referred by some comment.
And now I want to delete it as there is no reason for it.

Comment: Why do you think you should be able to? If you want the devs to consider your feature request, you need to explain what damage is done by not being able to close a room and why being able to do so will benefit the site. Otherwise, this looks like a dupe of the question you've linked to. Right now, though, this is a discussion, not a feature request... you're not asking for a feature, you're asking for clarification.

Comment: If you want a chatroom frozen or deleted, flag a message in it for moderator attention and ask them to do it.

Answer (score 5):

Why? Because adding that feature would be useful for a vanishingly small number of rooms, and isn't even needed.. The room will be automatically deleted for you after long enough with no activity, so there's no real advantage to *also* having the ability to "close" the room now.

Just forget the room exists and go do something else. There's no need to spend time and money on creating a feature for this, since it wouldn't solve any problem.